Is it possible to run Power Automate Desktop flows using Access?
I need to know if it's possible, and if you could provide me with any related documentation.
I've been trying to do it in Power Apps, but I encounter too many restrictions on the platform, so I'm looking into Access and VBA.

It's not clear what your intention is... Would you like to automate business task in VBA ?

Yes, I want to create a form in Access and then use VBA functions. From the click event, I want to be able to execute a flow if possible, although I haven't found a way to do this yet

Possibly can create a URL that will run a flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/run-desktop-flows-url-shortcuts#create-a-run-url then maybe Access can call the URL by hyperlink or Shell command.

Update! I found this method that doesn't seem to require premium:
(I'm calling the desktop flow from Automate Cloud using an HTTP request)
From my click event in Access:
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim postData As String
    Dim responseText As String
    
    url = "your http post url"
                
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    With objHTTP
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send postData
    End With
    
    If objHTTP.Status = 202 Then
        MsgBox "Hi"
    Else
        If objHTTP.Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox "Error: " & objHTTP.Status
        End If
    End If
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Sub

I'm unsure if I can make unlimited HTTP requests; I'm new to Automate
